# Different results when using -Split

Tags: powershell

When I run: `($email.Body -split 'Active Directory User Name' -split 'Back to top')[1]`

On my machine, I get the following result

> String
>
> String
>
> String

(Basically, everything between the two splits is returned on its own line)
But when I run the same code on another machine, it returns:

> String   String
>
> String   String

Can anyone shed some light onto what might be happening here?

We are using the exact same version of PowerShell and have tried a number of IDEs

**EDIT**
Here is an example of the full string that would be in $email.Body:

> Employee Details
>
> Active Directory User Name
>
> STRING\STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING #
>
> STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING #
>
> STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING
>
> STRING
>
> Office Location
>
> STRING
>
> Back to top

Comment: Can you post a sample input string with which this behavior occurs?

Comment: Have you compared the types of the data being outputted?

Comment: Imo the second output is correct. On your machine open a PS like this: `powershell -NoProfile` and execute your example there. Still getting the first output? Btw: for a minimal example two lines of `STRING STRING` should be enough. Adjust your output accordingly, or is it part of the problem the output is not all upper case?

Comment: Using no profile and even on a fresh machine I get the same output as my own machine :\